# how to get values of a nested key from json file in bash using python one-liner?

Tags: python, json, bash, shell, parsing

I'm trying to fetch values of a nested key from json file in bash using python one-liner. Below given is my json file content.

```
{
    "conditional_ks": {
     "saturday":["reportdata_by_type"],
     "sunday":["rt_report","metadata"]
    }
}
```

I want all values ["reportdata_by_type","rt_report","metadata"] as a list.
I did like,

```
[root@testnode1 repair]# python -c "import json; print json.load(open('repair.json','r'))[\"conditional_ks\"].values()"

output: [[u'rt_report', u'metadata'], [u'reportdata_by_type']]
```

but i need output like ['rt_report','metadata','reportdata_by_type']

**Note:** repair.json is json file name.

one option is using `conditional_ks.*[]` which supposed to give output like:

```
 ["reportdata_by_type", "rt_report", "metadata" ]
```

But in bash i'm unable to use it.

Can anyone has solution to this, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like below i solved the problem :

```
python -c "import json; print reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,json.load(open('repair.json','r'))[\"conditional_ks\"].values())"
```

**output :** `[u'rt_report', u'metadata', u'reportdata_by_type']`

Answer (score 3):

```
python -c "import json; import itertools; print(list(itertools.chain(*(json.load(open(\"repair.json\", 'r'))[\"conditional_ks\"].values()))))"
```

I have tested the code in my computer and it works properly. May this be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As always, [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is the tool of choice for working with json from a command line:

```
$ jq '.conditional_ks.saturday + .conditional_ks.sunday' repair.json
[
  "reportdata_by_type",
  "rt_report",
  "metadata"
]
```

---

Edit: If your real data has more fields than just those two specific ones and you want to concatenate all the values of `conditional_ks` fields, then:

```
$ jq '[ .conditional_ks[] ] | flatten' repair.json
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try follow Script. $1 is your json file, like

```
./MyScript.sh 'PathToYourJsonFile'
```

MyScript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

content=$(cat "$1");
string="";

echo "[";
while read line; do

  split=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/.*\[\(.*\)\]/\1/' | sed -s 's/",/" /g');

  for i in $split; do
    echo "$i,"
  done

done< <(echo -n "$content" | grep "\:\[");

echo "]";
```

Result:

```
[
"reportdata_by_type",
"rt_report",
"metadata",
]
```

Comment: That will break if the input json has any differences from what OP posted, like an extra space before or after a colon, or an array spanning multiple lines, etc. Use JSON-aware programs to parse JSON, not regular expressions, for the same reason you shouldn't use them to try to handle XML. Way too fragile and error-prone.